# Spring Batch multithread throwing java.lang.Thread.State

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a web application developed using `Grails`, `Spring`, `Java` and `Hibernate`.

It contains a batch job implemented using `Spring Batch`. When I run the job without multithreading it works fine. As soon as I introduce partitioning (and every partition is handled by a different thread/multi threading) after some processing some of the thread get stuck in an infinite loop and never comes back.

Following is the stack trace when thread gets stuck.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap.getEntry(AbstractHashedMap.java:440)
at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractReferenceMap.getEntry(AbstractReferenceMap.java:405)
at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractReferenceMap.get(AbstractReferenceMap.java:230)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore.getObjectErrors(AbstractDatastore.java:160)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.Datastore$getObjectErrors.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.Datastore$getObjectErrors.call(Unknown Source)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormValidationApi.getErrors(GormValidationApi.groovy:137)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor580.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:793)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:776)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:164)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.InstanceMethodInvokingClosure.call(GormEnhancer.groovy:257)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureStaticMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureStaticMetaMethod.java:59)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1580)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1140)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3308)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1152)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.setupErrorsProperty(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:100)
```

This is just a portion of thread trace.

This trace only tells me about the a method in which my thread got stuck. It does not tell me any details and method is pretty big to search for a problem. Can any one please help me in this matter telling me:

1) What is wrong looking at the trace?

2) How can I see more detailed stack trace?

Comment: It's hard to tell the exact problem without more information. A guess is there some type of contention occurring either at the database level or within the code, based on the multi-threaded behavior causing the problem. Possibly check the database for contention. Another thought is to download the apache commons collections map source code and set break points or try to see exactly what is being attempted when the thread freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered exactly the same problem.

I use grails 1.3.7 and my service will get stuck in infinite loop exactly.

The problem is DomainClassGrailsPlugin is not thread safe

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7861

this is the patch to solve your problem

if your grails version < 1.6.3

patch this code to replace SoftThreadLocalMap.java and reinstall grails application

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using grails 2.0.3. it seems this issue has been resolved in 2.0.3. Do not know why my threads are still going in infinite loops.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful in finding the issue. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use jconsole to check whether the cpu is alway equals 100%(for one cpu core) , check out whether it is a infinite loop problem.

Comment: You answer was really helpful and the issue was in grails-datastore-core file as you have mentioned in your answer. SoftThreadLocalMap.java file was not thread safe. They have fixed this problem in grails-datastore-core version > 2. Thanks for you help.